# PhotoSwipe: Is there a way to attach an event handler to the 'init' event or when the plugin opens the lightbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

I'm using [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/) lightbox in conjuntion with [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousel for a project, and I want to have the carousel autoplay while the photoswipe lightbox is not open, but when the lightbox is opened, I want the autoplay to stop.

In the [PhotoSwipe API](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/api.html) they have a `close` and `destroy` event to listen for, but not an event for `init` or `open`. Has anyone found a good way to do this?

Something like:

```
$('#gallery').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true,
});

// ... Setup photoswipe...

pswp.listen('open', function() {
  $('#gallery').slickSetOption('autoplay', false, false);
});

pswp.listen('close', function() {
  $('#gallery').slickSetOption('autoplay', true, false);
});

pwsp.init();
```

Comment: hello! Are you willing to share your code? would it be easy to set up a fiddle or something? Does it work as expected?

Comment: The relevant code is posted in my answer below! :)

Comment: ... I meant if you could share your html as well :D

Comment: I just used the example code from both websites. I can't find the example I was working on at the moment, but let me know if you can't get it working, and if I find time, I'll try to get a fiddle up.

Comment: thanks for getting back to this, found my way through this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this, I found that you can just do what you need to do before init, then attach an event handler on `close`.

Also there's an issue with Slick where the autoplay doesn't turn off using the `slickSetOption` command as of version 1.3.15.

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/731

Here is my workaround for it based on one of the comments on the issue:

```
// ... Setup PhotoSwipe ...
slider.slickPause();
slider.find('.slick-list').off('mouseleave.slick');

gallery.listen('close', function() { 
  slider.slickPlay();
  slider.find('.slick-list').on('mouseleave.slick', function() {
    slider.slickPlay();
  });
});

gallery.init();
```