# PhotoSwipe autoplay with next()

Tags: javascript, slideshow, photoswipe

I try to make the photoswipe JS Image Gallery run as a slideshow, with this function:

```
function gallery_autoplay() {

    gallery.next();
    setTimeout(gallery_autoplay(),3000);

}

setTimeout(gallery_autoplay(),3000);
```

but ei get an error at line 1088 of photoswipe.js

Comment: I think someone good explain referring link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841324/photoswipe-is-there-a-way-to-attach-an-event-handler-to-the-init-event-or-whe

Answer (score 1):

You need `setInterval` not `setTimeout`

```
function gallery_autoplay() {
    gallery.next();
}
setInterval(gallery_autoplay,3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not including your whole code, but if I were to take a guess it would be that the variable you use the .next() function on doesn't exist or is initiated wrong.

Try this:

```
var gallery; //As a global variable
//then when you init the gallery just use that same variable
//for instance
function OpenPhotoSwipe() {
  var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
  var items = [{
    src:'',
    w:1,
    h:1
  }]
  var options = { modal:false,bgOpacity:0.7 };
  gallery = new PhotoSwipe(pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
  gallery.init();
}
//And then finally use setInterval to queue the transition
setInterval(function() {
  gallery.next();
},3000);
```

Hope this helps